# Dealing with very large images in Core Graphics on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I have a very large view(~8000x8000) that I'd like to take a screenshot of but my application is being terminated 1/4 times the screenshot code executes.  The code looks something like this:

```
// Render the view into a bitmap
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 
                                         _document.size.width, 
                                         _document.size.height, 
                                         8, 0, colorSpace, 
                                         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

// Convert the UI space to CG space
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -_document.size.height);

// Render the view
[_contentView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
CGImageRef screenshot = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);

// Cleanup
CGContextRelease(ctx);    
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Obviously it's going to use *alot* of memory.  Does anyone have any tricks working with very large images and coregraphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this is to open a PDF context and writing to that.  This way it uses file memory rather than video memory!

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't render the whole image at once, render a 500x8000 "band", write it out, release it, repeat 16 times.

Comment: Yes, I like that idea, but I expect renderInContext to have a "renderRect" type functionality.  Also, how do i stitch all of the rendered tiles together *without* reading them back in to memory?

Comment: Um....a read only mmap(2) might not count as "memory" for the purposes of your process being killed for over use of memory.   Maybe.   If you don't have other options it is worth a try.

Comment: You can stitch the tiles together directly on disk, not in memory. This method is better than the one you accepted because it lets you control the process. Plus, it's probably faster, if you don't actually need a PDF.